# How to run two different versions of the same rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to run two instances of the same application on ruby on rails. Let's I've a rails application myApp and I've version 18 and 19 of it. How can I've them running simultaneously in production?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How you differentiate both version? With git branch?

Comment: different git branches for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two versions to run at the same time by configuring them under two different paths and hosts in your webserver.

What you should avoid, however, it to share the same resources (for instance the database). If your database schema has changed, the one with the legacy schema will not be able to run.

Comment: but how do you connect them to different branches?

Comment: Clone the repo twice, and checkout to the specific version you want to use.